# How to decrease /dev/sda1 partition size?

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, virtualbox, vagrant

[image]

This is defualt CentOS7 partition download from Vagrant box package except the disk size I change from 40GB to 80GB
How can I decrease /dev/sda1 partition size without losing Boot data?
And Is fresh CentOS7 have no physical volume normal?

[image]

[image]

/dev/sda1 have a lot of free space.I want to change it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. XFS filesystem [doesn't support shrinking](https://xfs.org/index.php/Shrinking_Support). If you need a different partitioning, you'll need to install CentOS manually without using Vagrant. You can simply download the ISO image and use it in VirtualBox to boot from and do a fresh installation. CentOS installation guide can be found [here](https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/Simple_Installation/).

> And Is fresh CentOS7 have no physical volume normal?

Standard installation uses [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29), but it is also possible to use partitions, I assume the Vagrant image has only single partition for `/`.